# Composer is not updating package to newest version

Tags: composer-php

**tl;dr**: *I'm having troubles forcing Composer to get latest changes to my local  package. It seems, that problem is caused by latest change not being part of any release in packages repository.*

I'm using [`yii2-language-picker`](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-language-picker) in my project and have added it with instructions given in docs:

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist lajax/yii2-language-picker "1.*"
```

Recently extension's author has made [a change](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-language-picker/commit/21d19af6601cbd5a4354cc6bf8d1ac619f89dbf7). However, this change [is not part of any release](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-language-picker/releases/tag/1.1.1), because it is [1 commit after latest release](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-language-picker/compare/1.1.1...master). If I'm not mistaken (I'm quite new to Composer), this causes Composer to not update my local package -- after `composer update` or `composer install` I'm getting `Nothing to install or update`.

Because that latest change is not a part of any relase, I was suggested to edit `composer.json` file, change `"lajax/yii2-language-picker": "1.*"` in `required` section to `"lajax/yii2-language-picker": "*"` and issue another `composer update`.

I have also completely removed this package and installed it again with both `"1.*"` and `"**"`.

None of these brought any effects. Composer still claims, that there is nothing to install or update.

What can be causing this situation? Is there anything I can do in this case, or the only option I'm left with is to sit down and wait until package / repository author will make that change part of another release?

I tried to manually update this package, but after `composer status` I'm getting `No local changes` and I'm woried, that all these changes will be lost, once actual package update will be released. Should I make any local changes in this situation or should I sit and wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing 1.* to dev-master probably solves your problem.

Comment: Note that depending on branches very likely will break the whole package at one point, making your software unable to be updated anymore, and preventing you from adding new packages.